# Oracle subquery with MAX operator taking very long

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a web application that was using a very complex database view to retrieve some data which appeared to be very slow, taking up to 3 minutes to complete only . After a thorough investigation I've found what was the cause of the problem.
In my code I was using the following condition in the WHERE clause to retrieve only the LAST element of a joined table:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MY_TABLE
JOIN TABLE_JOIN_XX tableA on ....
..lots of other joins ...
WHERE
 tableA.id = 
   (SELECT MAX (id) FROM TABLE_JOIN_XX tableB WHERE tableA.id_parent = tableB.id_parent)
```

I have then changed the condition in the following way:

```
 tableA.id >= ALL 
   (SELECT id FROM TABLE_JOIN_XX tableB WHERE tableA.id_parent = tableB.id_parent)
```

and now the query takes only a couple of seconds.

Now I'm wondering why there is this huge difference in execution time between using the MAX operator and the ALL operator. I am quite surprised indeed. I am no DBA and not very expert in query optimization, but maybe there is something that I don't know and that I should take in consideration while developing my queries for database access.

Or maybe is something related to a problem in that specific Oracle instance and not to the query? I've never noticed this problem in other instances of the same database.

Looking at the explain plan I've noticed that in the second case (and not in the first one) Oracle replaces the ALL operator with a NOT EXISTS:

```
 not exists 
  (select 0 from TABLE_JOIN_XX tableA 
     where tableA.id_parent=:b1 and LNNVL (id<=:b2))
```

Any suggestion?
Many thanks.

Comment: Why do you think `tableA.id = (SELECT MAX (id) FROM TABLE_JOIN_XX tableB WHERE tableA.id = tableB.id)` is equal `tableA.id >= ALL 
   (SELECT id FROM TABLE_JOIN_XX tableB WHERE tableA.id = tableB.id)`?

Comment: id is actually an id_parent, i corrected the query now. Conceptually A = MAX (set of elements) if A >= each of (set of elements)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems malformed.  This is your statement:

```
WHERE tableA.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE_JOIN_XX tableB WHERE tableA.id = tableB.id)
```

You are doing a correlated subquery on the column `id`.  Then you are choosing the maximum value.  The subquery can only return `tableA.id` or `NULL`, so this is equivalent to:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_JOIN_XX tableB WHERE tableA.id = tableB.id)
```

Perhaps Oracle is getting a bit confused.  In any case, by using `MAX()`, you are saying that all the values need to be processed, so Oracle is probably doing that.  In fact, it only needs to find one row with a value.

An index on `TABLE_JOIN_XX(id)` should help this query even more.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in copying here the query. The id on the where condition is actually an id_parent, otherwise it wouldn't make sense. tableA and tableB have the same id_parent and I select from tableA the element which has id = maximum of the ids related to the same parent